# Quais as necessidades de se manter um atributo `name` em uma tag `HTML`?

Tags: html

Quais as necessidades de se manter um atributo `name` em uma tag `HTML`? suas características são iguais as do atributo `id` que ainda possui outras utilidades como ser a chave dos arrays `$_POST` e `$_GET` do **PHP**.

Comment: Mas você está dizendo que o `id` do HTML é chave do `$_POST` e `$_GET` no PHP? Não é, só o `name` vai parar nessas arrays do PHP.

Comment: Obrigado por considerar a resposta boa ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Objetivo

Geralmente, o atributo name serve para representar uma coleção de valores, enviados através de um formulário, para o servidor.

## Outras Utilidades

**Submissão de formulários para IFRAMES**

Ricardo, além de servir como chaves para `POST` e `GET`, uma outra funcionalidade que eu conheço é para fazer uma submissão de formulário para um `iframe`, ao invés de atualizar a página.

Exemplo:

```
<form target="meu_iframe" action="form.php">
  <input type="text" name="nome" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<iframe name="meu_iframe">
```

Consequentemente, quando for feito o submit do formulário, o resultado será exibido no `iframe`, ao invés de atualizar a página. Ainda que o `action` esteja apontando para outra página, a renderização da mesma se dará dentro do `iframe`.

Essa é uma funcionalidade que eu conheço. Talvez possa existir outras, vamos ver as outras respostas :)

**Acesso ao Formulário Via Javascript**

Me lembro também que é possível dar um `name` para um formulário, mesmo que o mesmo não seja processado pelo servidor (como foi afirmado numa das respostas)

É possível fazer isso:

```
<form name="matricula">
 ...
</form>
```

Assim, podemos acessar esse formulário facilmente pelo Javascript:

```
document.matricula.submit();
```

Answer (score 8):

O atributo `name` é adequado para formulários, para identificar componentes no servidor. O atributo `id` é adequado para computações do lado do cliente.

O atributo `name` também pode ocorrer repetidas vezes com o mesmo valor em elementos que se repetem na página (caixas de marcação, por exemplo). Já repetir um `id` é receita para problemas.

Answer (score 4):

São os nomes dos paramentros que são enviado em uma requisição GET ou POST.
No HTML:

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name_input_1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="name_input_2" value="">
</form>
```

No PHP:

```
$name_input_1 = $_POST['name_input_1'];
$name_input_2 = $_POST['name_input_2'];
```

Answer (score -1):

O atributo `name` é string especificando um nome para o controle de entrada. Esse nome é enviado junto com o valor do controle quando os dados do formulário são enviados.

Considere o `name` atributo necessário (mesmo que não seja). Se uma entrada não foi `name` especificada ou `name` está vazia, o valor da entrada não é enviado com o formulário! (Controles desabilitados, botões de opção desmarcados, caixas de seleção desmarcadas e botões de redefinição também não são enviados.)

Sabendo dessa informação teórica é hora de praticar.

Quando uma pesquisa é feita no StackOverflow o atributo `name` é usado para armazenar este valor e enviar para o Back-end via método [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET). O Back-end recebe essa informação e devolve o resultado para usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]