# Qual é a finalidade das propriedades "id" e "name" de uma tag HTML?

Tags: html, característica-linguagem

Quando criamos uma *tag* em HTML podemos atribuir valores a suas propriedades, entretanto, a propriedade `id` e `name`, eu percebo que são muito utilizadas e geralmente os valores que são atribuídos a elas são os mesmos, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Exemplo para ilustração.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p size=2>O <spam style="font-weight:bolder;">input text</spam> esta com as propriedades id e name definidas com o mesmo valor<br> que é "nome".</p>        
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" size=25 />
  </body>
 </html>
```

Qual é a finalidade dessas duas propriedades `id` e `name` e se existe alguma diferença em relação uma com a outra, já que ambas guardam o mesmo valor?

Comment: Se tiver alguma sugestão de melhoria pode deixar um comentário por favor.  Não é a primeira vez que isso esta acontecendo com as minhas perguntas.

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais as necessidades de se manter um atributo `name` em uma tag `HTML`?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97141/28595)

Comment: Mas acho que essa só responde parcialmente a pergunta.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

De certa maneira ambos servem para identificar o elemento. De maneira geral pode dizer-se que o `id` é importante para o browser, manipulação do DOM e CSS; e o `name` é importante para o servidor.

Por regra usa-se o `id` para identificar o elemento no DOM e aplicar regras de CSS com o operador `#`. Ainda que seja possivel usar CSS no elemento com um seletor `[name="algo"]` isso é raro.

O name é principalmente usado para elementos de `<form>`, ou seja para campos de inserção de dados e é exatamente o `name` que identifica no servidor o campo. Quando fazes o envio de uma `form`, os campos dela vão para o servidor num objeto cujas chaves são o `name` que esses elementos têm.

Pode haver mais do que um elemento com o mesmo `name`, por exemplo:

```html
Opção 1<input value="1" type="radio" name="algo">
Opção 2<input value="2" type="radio" name="algo">
Opção 3<input value="3" type="radio" name="algo">
```

mas não pode haver mais do que um elemento com o mesmo `id`.

A [descrição da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) diz assim:

> **ID** - Often used with CSS to style a specific element. The value of this attribute must be unique.

*Comum usar relacionado com CSS para aplicar estilos a um elemento. Tem de ser único.*

> **Name** - Name of the element. For example used by the server to identify the fields in form submits.

*Nome do elemento. Por exemplo usado pelo servidor para identificar os campos submetidos*

Answer (score 8):

O `name` serve para nominar cada conteúdo quando se submete o formulário.

Pode-se perguntar se não poderia aproveitar o `id` para isto. Não pode porque a finalidade do `id` é prover um identificador único para cada *tag* no documento. Você pode ter o mesmo nome para *tags* diferentes de um formulário, ou mesmo ter o mesmo nome em formulários diferentes no mesmo documento cuja semântica sejam idênticas. O `name` não precisa ser único e semanticamente serve a outro propósito.

Então em um `radio` você terá *tags* distintas com o mesmo nome, afinal é o mesmo controla, apesar de serem diversas *tags*.

Outra situação: pense que existem dois formulários diferentes que possuem comportamentos diferentes mas os dados são os mesmos. Vamos dizer que um elemento pede uma cidade e ou outro também. Que nome você dá para ambos? Provavelmente `cidade`, afinal é a mesma coisa. A aplicação que vai receber a informação no servidor espera receber o dado com este nome, não importa qual formulário foi enviado. O `id` de cada uma das *tags* são completamente diferentes.

O `id` é um controle de programação do documento que pode ser usado para estilizar com CSS ou manipular/acessar individualmente com JS, ou até mesmo usado como âncora de URL. O `name` é usado para indicar de qual controle vem aquele dado. Eu já vi códigos usando o `name` como se fosse um `id`. Até funciona, mas é conceitualmente errado.

`name` podia ser usado em outros elementos do HTML, mas em HTML isto não é usado mais, ficando só para formulários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Em um formulário o `id` apenas é usado pra manipular o DOM ou diferenciar de outro elementos. Pode ser usando via JS para manipular um `<select>` e/ou um `<input>` por exemplo. Alguns plugins como o [nice-select2](https://bluzky.github.io/nice-select2/) usam o `id` para alterar o css do `<select>` do [Twitter Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/select/) que não da suporte a `live-search` por exemplo.