# Marcar checkbox com retornos na DIV

Tags: jquery

Neste Form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-id=1" name="status_entrega" id="status_entrega">
<div id="retorno_1" style="display:none; float:left">Atualizado</div>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" data-id=2" name="status_entrega" id="status_entrega">
<div id="retorno_2" style="display:none; float:left">Atualizado</div>
```

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$('#status_entrega').click(function(){
    var id_pedido = $("#status_entrega").attr("data-id");
    $("#retorno_"+id_pedido).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Porém, o primeiro item consigo marcar como checado, o segundo e os demais, não consigo nem marcar... Não retorna a mensagem de atualização. Alguém consegue ajudar?

Atualização:

Conforme ajuda do Sérgio, eu modifiquei, mas preciso que, ao desmarcar, envie também a solicitação de atualização. Segue o codigo atualizado:

```
$('[name="status_entrega"]').click(function() {
    var id_pedido = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#retorno_" + id_pedido).toggle(this.checked);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../ajax/getTransacaoOK',
        success: function (response) {

            $("#retorno_" + id_pedido).html("Atualizando...");
            setTimeout(function(){

                $("#retorno_" + id_pedido).html("Atualizado!");

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#retorno_" + id_pedido).html("");
                },1000);

            },2000);    
        },
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens IDs duplicados... [eles têm de sêr únicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127331/129).

Podes usar o `name="status_entrega"` como seletor e fazer assim:

```js
$('[name="status_entrega"]').click(function() {
    var id_pedido = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#retorno_" + id_pedido).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" data-id="1" name="status_entrega" id="status_entrega">
    <div id="retorno_1" style="display:none; float:left">Atualizado</div>
</section>
<section>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" data-id="2" name="status_entrega" id="status_entrega">
    <div id="retorno_2" style="display:none; float:left">Atualizado</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfeita solução. Obrigado! :)

Comment: Eu fiz um ajuste nele, mas quando clicar de volta, ele precisa enviar a ação novamente... exemplo, marquei, enviou ação, desmarquei, enviou ação novamente.... mas ao desmarcar, não envia, atualizei o meu codigo.

Comment: @AndréBaill faz sim, só que está escondido. Mas para ficar ainda melhor podias fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/m443k17f/

Comment: Ok, ai pra eu passar o id do pedido, eu faço dentro do ajax...  data: id_pedido? :)

Comment: @AndréBaill `data: {id_pedido: id_pedido}`

Comment: Neste caso @Sergio, eu vou enviar 1 se for ativo e 0 ser for inativo, dessa forma, eu preciso passar qual é o valor do checkbox?

Comment: Isto var status_entrega = $("status_entrega").val(); deve resolver né? Porque ai eu pego o valor do checkbox

Comment: @AndréBaill `data: {id_pedido: id_pedido, estado: this.checked},`

Comment: Ahh bacana, certo, vou tentar.