# Definir varios "id" numa tag HTML

Tags: html, html5, id

**`HTML`** permite definir varias **`class`** numa unica balisa.
Curiosamente tentei fazer o mesmo, tentando definir varios **`id`** numa uma **`tag`** :

**`<div id="id1 id2 id3">Tester plusieurs id</div>`**

Nao funcionou, ou seja HTML ignorou todas essas classes.

Sera que estou a proceder de modo errado ou simplesmente nao é permitido por HTML ?

OBS : **Simplesmente uma curiosidade**

Comment: Podes explicar porque precisas de "ids" diferentes? são dados que precisas guardar ou estás só a experimentar e queres saber porque não funciona?

Comment: Simplesmente uma curiosidade

Comment: Nesse caso é [duplicada dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127330/129) ou de [esta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11130/129).

Comment: Nao propriamente @Sergio

Comment: Qual é a diferença ou o que falta?

Comment: @AndréPKA viste a minha pergunta? Queria saber que informação falta na outra pergunta? para completar lá ou dar uma resposta mais completa aqui.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplos *ids* por elemento não é permitido:

> O valor deste atributo não deve conter lacunas (espaços, tabulações
>   etc.). Navegadores tratam IDs inadequadas que contenham lacunas como
>   se as lacunas fossem parte do ID. Em contraste com o atributo class,
>   que permite múltiplos valores separados por espaço, os elementos podem
>   ter somente um único ID.

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 2):

Quando você utiliza um id ele deve ser único para o seu determinado elemento (TAG).
Ja a class pode ser repetida e pode conter quantas você precisar num mesmo elemento.

Evite repetir ids numa mesma página, caso precise indentificar vários elementos com um mesmo nome, utilize class.

Comment: Ele perguntou sobre múltiplos IDs diferentes em um mesmo div. Não sobre IDs iguais.

Comment: Lê de novo "Quando você utiliza um id ele deve ser único para o seu determinado elemento (TAG)". eu apenas complementei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Acho que não pode fazer isso amigo. Você pode usar mais de uma classe(já criadas)em um class de uma tag.