# Adicionar e remover classe quando usa getElementById JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript

Criei a função para adicionar a classe ativo no ID que foi clicado, mas se eu clicar em outro eu quero que remova a classe do anterior e adicione ativo no que foi clicado atualmente.

Com `document.querySelectorAll` eu consigo, porque gera um Nodelist, então eu faço um `forEach` e dá certo, mas com o `getElementById` eu não estou conseguindo.

```
function activeClass(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const element = event.target;
  const id = element.getAttribute('id');
  const article = document.getElementById(id);

  article.classList.add('ativo');
}
```

Comment: Cara, eu não entendi sua pergunta, você quer adicionar um id em um elemento quando for clicado nele e depois remover a classe anterior ?

Comment: Essa função compara se há dois ID's iguais na página, se houver ela vai adicionar a classe ativo, mas se eu clicar clicar em outro local eu preciso que remova a classe do anterior e adicione no atual. Consegui explicar?

Comment: Vc sabe que não eh correto ter dois elementos com ID iguais, dois ID com o mesmo nome sempre da problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127330/qual-%c3%a9-a-finalidade-das-propriedades-id-e-name-de-uma-tag-html/

Comment: Mas neste meu caso aqui é preciso, pois estou utilizando um elemento para interagir com outro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depois de muito custo eu consegui resolver o problema **(do meu jeito)**.

Segue o código:

```
const selectMapID = document.querySelectorAll('.map a');
  const selectArticles = document.querySelectorAll('.map article');
  selectArticles[1].classList.add('ativo');

  selectMapID.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', showState);
  })

  function showState(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const element = event.target;
    const id = element.getAttribute('id');
    const article = document.getElementById(id);

    selectArticles.forEach( (section) => {
      section.classList.remove('ativo');
    } );
    article.classList.add('ativo');
  }
```

Obrigado a todos pela colaboração!

Comment: Não era mais simples usar a solução que o Sergio propôs? Qual é a ideia de você obter o alvo do evento, pegar o valor do `id` dele para depois buscar o mesmo elemento? No seu código `article` e `element` serão exatamente o mesmo elemento, ficou bem confuso.

Answer (score 2):

Não podes ter mais que um elemento com o mesmo ID numa página.

Tens de usar classes e podes fazer assim:

```js
function activeClass(clicado) {
  const clicaveis = document.querySelectorAll('.clicavel');
  clicaveis.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('ativo', el === clicado));
}
```

```css
.clicavel {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: light-grey;
  transition: background-color .15s;
}

.ativo {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a class="clicavel" onclick="activeClass(this)">Produto A</a>
<a class="clicavel" onclick="activeClass(this)">Produto B</a>
```

A ideia é teres os elementos que fazem parte dessa lógica todos com a mesma classe, e depois trocar a classe consoante o que for clicado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma variavel global para guardar o id `ativo`, ou guardar o proprio elemento, e na hora de setar um novo elemento `ativo` você remove a class do elemento da variavel e seta essa variavel com o novo elemento..

```js
let ativo;

function activeClass(event) {
  
  if (ativo !== undefined){
    ativo.classList.remove('ativo');  
  }
  ativo = event;
  
  event.classList.add('ativo');  
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1" onclick="activeClass(this)">div 1</div>
<div id="div-2" onclick="activeClass(this)">div 2</div>
<div id="div-3" onclick="activeClass(this)">div 3</div>
```

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar esse teu exemplo e não consegui, com o código que postei na conversa tu consegue fazer um exemplo?